# How to Wordpress dynamic url prefix based on taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing an offers site using wordpress. We are trying to offer different offers regarding the city.

So we have two taxonomies (category and city).

The thing is that I don't want to use the normal url structure, I wish it could be:

```
root -> http://site .com/city-taxonomy 
category -> http://site .com/city-taxonomy/category 
offer -> http://site .com/city-taxonomy/offer-slug
```

**Basically I want to split my site in cities without using a multiple site (network)  in wordpress so i don't need to repeat categories or custom fields. I want to maintain the current wordpress url system how its working but adding the prefix I can read from php using GET**

The if anybody manage to do this, I'd like to know how will you handle the url creating in the template, using the city as a prefix, global variable should be enoght.

I thought about creating city as category and subcategories, but I'd need to repeat all the subcategories for each one.

One offer could be included in several cities and one category.

I readed about the rewrite rules functions in wordpress php but I think it should be faster if I do this in htaccess.

The thing is that after including a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?city=$1 [L]
```

This is always redirecting me to search functionality in wordpress, and I don't know if this is a good long term solution.

**I just need to have this first parameter so set a global variable so I can modify the db requests, the rest part of the url should work the same wordpress is doing.**

We could say is the same functionality "language" is doing, adding a prefix to the url so you can determine language, but I don't know how to implement that

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

From your `dashboard` Go to `Settings->Permalinks` and select `post name` from there.

Comment: I think it won't make it work, since I need taxonomy based url system, not only regarding the post.

Comment: It works for all category and taxonomy. I suggest you may give it a try!

Comment: But I need to dynamic parameters /city/category  Two taxonomies in same url

Comment: That is to managed by code. Your url settings would do what you want to do by .htaccess

Comment: I just need to have this first parameter so set a global variable so I can modify the db requests, the rest part of the url should work the same wordpress is doing.

Comment: We could say is the same functionality "language" is doing, adding a prefix to the url so you can determine language, but I don't know how to implement that